# SSRS footer with info about devided chapters

Tags: reporting-services

I have made the report which divides into several chapters due to parameter. In parameter we type numbers of last row in the chapter. So it looks like this:

If we bring in parameter “100; 200; 400” and overall report contains 1000 rows, it will create 4 chapters: 1-100, 101-200, 201-400 and 401-1000. I used this report code to do this:

```
Dim ggg As Integer=0
Function Set_ggg(a as Integer) as integer
    ggg=ggg+a
    return ggg
End Function

Function Get_ggg() as Integer
    return ggg
End Function 

Function Null_ggg() as Integer
    ggg=0
    return ggg
End Function 

Function nGr(n as Integer) as Integer
    Dim prev as Integer
    Dim t as Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim UsedN as Integer()={0}
    prev=0
    For i = 0 To Report.Parameters!N_Sprav.Value.GetUpperBound(0) 
        If prev<n and n<=Report.Parameters!N_Sprav.Value(i) Then  'and Array.IndexOf(UsedN, n)=-1 
            exit for
        Else 
            prev=Report.Parameters!N_Sprav.Value(i)
        End If
    Next 

    UsedN(UsedN.GetUpperBound(0))=n

    ReDim Preserve UsedN(UsedN.GetUpperBound(0)+1)
    if IsNothing(i) then
        i=0
    End if
    Return i
End Function
```

Now I need to do the footer after every chapter with expression where number of rows and range of it must be displayed. For foregoing example it must display: 100 rows from #1 to #100, 100 rows from #101 to #200, 200 rows from #201 to 400 and 600 rows from #401 to #1000, respectively.

I succeeded to display count of rows in this way: `CStr(Count(Fields!ID__з_п_ок.Value,"Gr1"))`

But I have no idea how to do “from # to #” It seems to be easy, but I can’t find it out.